# How can i add contact on existing Group in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, abaddressbook, abaddressbooksource

I am working on contact app in which i want to add the contact with 3 different groups (i.e. A, B, C). And for adding (creating) new contact using native contact create.

```
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
ABUnknownPersonViewController *controller = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
controller.displayedPerson = person;
controller.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

This will be add the contact on contact book. But i wish to add with Group Like A,B and C.

How can i add this contact in the group with the use of native Add Contact screen.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

i hope it will work ,

You can achieve that by using `ABNewPersonViewController` available in the **Addressbook** Framework:

**Below iOS 9:**

```
ABNewPersonViewController *addContactVC = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
addContactVC.newPersonViewDelegate      = self;
UINavigationController *navController   = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addContactVC];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

**iOS 9 or greater:**

You can use CNContactViewController of  **ContactsUI** Framework :

```
CNContactViewController *addContactVC = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForNewContact:contact];
addContactVC.delegate                 = self;
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addContactVC];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
```